# Multiple Oracle DB's on network

Tags: networking, database, oracle

Im about to install a std edition of oracle 10g on my own machine for testing only.
However we allready have an Oracle db on our network.

Is it possible that I might cause any problems for the other runnig db, by installing my own?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problems at all! You can even have the DBs run the same `ORA_SID`, just make sure you differentiate properly in your `TNSNAMES.ORA`